# Error al ordenar

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Verán, estoy implementando una cola circular que ordene sus elementos alfabéticamente, pero he tenido un error y espero puedan ayudarme

Al ejecutar el programa ingreso nombres al azar y al mostrar la cola si los ordena alfabéticamente pero cuando elimino un elemento e ingreso uno de nuevo, este ya no queda ordenado, para ser claros

Y finalmente la función de ordenar

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Estás ejecutando `ordenarCola` nuevamente luego de usar `push`?

Comment: Si, al entrar de nuevo a la opcion que muestra la cola, primero mando la funcion de `ordenarCola`, deberia ordenar y despues mostrar

Comment: Creo que `pop` no es compatible con `ordenarCola`, si no me equivoco `pop` solo toma el valor en la ubicación determinada por `frente` , luego incrementa en uno este valor y disminuye el valor de `e`, yo supongo que `frente` es como el punto de inicio actual, entonces `ordenarCola` debería tener en cuenta eso, ya que esta función siempre empieza a ordenar desde la posición 0 sin tener en cuenta el campo `frente`. El argumento `cantidad` cuando usas la función ¿como lo sacas?.

Comment: Respondiendo respecto a de donde viene el  `cantidad`  para poder mandarle cuantos va a ordenar a la funcion  `ordenarCola`  cada vez que entra a la opción insertar aumento  `cantidad`  en 1 y a su vez cuando entra a la opción retirar decremento en 1 `cantidad`  así obtengo ese argumento

Comment: De ser incompatible pop debería cambiar el como retiro de la cola, cierto?

Comment: Osea `cantidad` es el valor actual de `e` ¿no?, si esto es cierto es como te digo, las funciones que te señale no son compatibles.

Comment: Creo que el detalle está en modificar `ordenarCola`

Comment: Ok, si modificare el parámetro que paso  `int cantidad ` por el de  `frente`

Comment: Creo no es necesario ese argumento, ahí te paso una alternativa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las funciones `pop` y `ordenarCola` no son compatibles ya que `pop` modifica el valor de `frente` que sería el punto de inicio actual, entonces `ordenarCola` debería tener en cuenta eso, ya que esta función siempre empieza a ordenar desde la posición 0 sin tener en cuenta el campo `frente`. Para que la función tenga en cuenta eso deberías modificarla de tal manera que empiece a ordenar a partir de la ubicación determinada por `frente` y ordene tantos elementos como el valor actual de `e`, algo así:

```
 void ordenarCola(cola *miCola)
{
    int cantidad = miCola->e;//la cantidad de elementos la extraes de aquí.
    int inicio = miCola->frente;//punto inicial
    char temp[50];
    //cola miColacopia;->esto no se está usando
    int i, j;
    for (i = inicio; i != (inicio+cantidad - 1); ++i)//fijate en el valor inicial y el final
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j != inicio+cantidad; ++j)//lo mismo aquí.
        {
            if (strcmp(miCola->a[i], miCola->a[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, miCola->a[i]);
                strcpy(miCola->a[i], miCola->a[j]);
                strcpy(miCola->a[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```